# What is an md5sum?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

Anybody could explain me what is exactly md5sum, and could tell me typical problems/solutions about this?

Regards

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/48053/what-is-an-md5sum?/) by [Sanxano](https://answers.ros.org/users/1103/sanxano/) on ROS Answers with karma: 70 on 2012-11-11

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

An md5 sum is a hash. Have a look at the [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Md5sum). In ROS, it is used to verify that subscribers and publishers are using exactly the same message definitions, i.e. the md5 sum is computed from message definition files.

If you get md5 mismatches, then your messages are inconsistent. Make sure that you are using the same ros version on all computers and that you recompile all nodes if you change a message definition.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-11-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 11